text summarization with LLM Llama 3.1 8B Instruct
I need to do abstractive text summarization with LLM Llama 3.1 8B Instruct. My question is how do I do this methodologically?
Here is how I propose going about it

Load CNN Daily dataset for text summarization with features (article and highlisths)
Load model and tokenizer in local disk in kaggle
Use Lora for parameter training of LLM
Preprocess dataset with tokenizer for Instruct model with input prompt
Training with TrainingArguments and SFTTrainer

Does this aforementioned procedure suffice or I might need additional input?
Appliyng parameter training for LLM

I will provide a code snippet, this will guide you on how to build your own LLM. I would advise you learn some methodologies such as RAG-Rank, RAG-Fusion.
The first step is to download ollama follow this link always makes sure the app is running whenever you want to run the python class which I have provided below.
import ollama
from operator import itemgetter
from langchain.retrievers.multi_query import MultiQueryRetriever
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, PromptTemplate
from langchain_community.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_text_splitters import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredPDFLoader
from ollama.embeddings import OllamaEmbeddings
from ollama import ChatOllama
from langchain.retrievers.multi_query import MultiQueryRetriever
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough


# Define a prompt for the RAG model
SYSTEM_PROMPT = """ You are very helpful assistant and also 
    an expert in summarizing documents,
    use all available resources to generate answers to the questions asked.
    You can return queries that you think are relevant to the question asked. \
    You will be asked to summarize a document here is the question: {question} \n
"""

def read_pdf_file(data):
    """
    Retrieve the data from the file

    Args: data: The data to be retrieved

    Returns: list: List of documents
    """

    local_path = "your_pdf_file_path"

    try:
       # Local PDF file uploads
       if local_path:
          loader = UnstructuredPDFLoader(file_path=local_path)
          data = loader.load()
       else:
          logging.error("Upload a PDF file")
    except Exception as e:
        raise  # Re-raise the exception to stop further execution

    # Split and chunk
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=7500, chunk_overlap=100)
    chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(data)

    try:
        ollama.embeddings(
            model="llama_3.1_8B_instruct",
            # prompt='Llamas are members of the camelid family',
        )
        embedding_model = (OllamaEmbeddings(model="llama_3.1_8B_instruct"),)
        vectorstore_db = FAISS.from_documents(
            documents=chunks, embedding=embedding_model
        )
        vectorstore_db.save_local("faiss_index")
        vector_retriever = vectorstore_db.as_retriever()

    except Exception as e:
        raise  # Re-raise the exception to stop further execution
    
    return vector_retriever

# RAG FUSION

    def main(self) -> str:
        """
        Implement the RAG fusion
        Args:
        question: The question to be answered

        Returns:
        str: The answer to the question
        """
        LLM_PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
        input_variables=["question"],
        template="""You are an AI language model assistant. Your task is to generate summaries. Provide these alternative questions separated by newlines.
        Original question: {question}""",
       )
        template = """Answer the question based ONLY on the following context:
            {context}
            Question: {question}
            """
        prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_template(template)
        
        local_model = "llama_3.1_8B_instruct." #find the real name from ollama and download it
        llm = ChatOllama(model=local_model)
        retriever = read_pdf_file(self.data)
        retriever = MultiQueryRetriever.from_llm(
          retriever, llm, prompt=LLM_PROMPT 
        )

        chain = (
            {"context": retriever, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
            | prompt
            | llm
            | StrOutputParser()
        )
        response = chain.invoke("summarize this documents about climate change")
        print(response)
 

